# Create unique integer id column for result rows of union query

Tags: postgresql

I have a view as below in which I union several tables and I'm thinking it might be a good idea to have a unique row number for each row in the result set. The prescient reason is I have an admin tool which doesn't know I'm using a view rather than an ordinary table, and which expects a unique id to be present,  but I'm now speculating it might be worth doing more generally (i.e. it may make sense to do this in certain theoretical terms - discussion on this would be welcome). Wondering how to do this in postgresql.

```sql
CREATE VIEW subscriptions AS (
    SELECT subscriber_id, course, end_at 
    FROM subscriptions_individual_stripe

    UNION ALL SELECT subscriber_id, course, end_at
    FROM subscriptions_individual_bank_transfer

    ORDER BY end_at DESC);
```

#### Discussion

The reason these are separate tables is of course that they are actually different entities, and yet I also need to be able to contemplate them in a combined way, hence the VIEW. This is my way of avoiding so-called 'polymorphic relationships' in certain popular web frameworks.

I have a tool that expects an id and while my first thought was that views don't need a unique key, on the other hand, maybe they do...?
Reason being two records could exist in one of the UNIONed tables which were only unique by virtue of the primary key. If one does not include the primary key, the union should remove one of those, so a record would be lost.  Should we also take that into account, i.e. select the primary key (here an integer id) for each of the UNIONed tables, but, "convert it" to some other unique id, so the view has its own unique integer primary key? Of course this won't be usable in terms of referencing anything in the original UNIONed tables, but I'm OK with that (The view is a terminal point of my analysis, I don't intend to do anything further with it, and of course it is not writable).

**Update**

I'm accepting S-Man's answer below because it is a solution to the question I asked, however, as pointed out, the `row_number()` must not be treated as if it was a real identifier because it will not be.

So as an important aside, I'm left wondering what `row_number()` is really intended for then. Perhaps it's (mainly? occasionally?) useful where you want to output some query when you plan to export the data somewhere else (i.e. seems almost *spreadsheet*-ish), and you abandon any sense of it being integrated with the rest of your database?

Table inheritance may be better as Abelisto has pointed out in the comments.

Comment: If I understand your requirements correctly. The best and the most efficient way could be the complex ID like (source+source_id) Or even more look at the [Inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html) - it could be more useful then artificial view.

Comment: @Abelisto  interesting idea, I hadn't thought of that. However, given the constraints of the web framework I am using, I think there are times when it assumes an integer id. Therefore while I definitely appreciate your suggestion in terms of purity and interest, i.e. to create a new composite key (of table name concatenated to primary key id of each UNIONed table?), it is also likely going to be useful to know how to produce a single integer value to identify each row. Of course, this cannot be the incrementing ids from the UNIONed tables, because they will certainly duplicate one another.

Comment: Use one sequence to generate IDs for many table? Honestly it is hard to understand for me. If you ask me: "how to design the schema for this task?" I then provide the SQL script for this. But, as I understand, you already have some working DB schema which, I think, you do not want to change... How to solve the problem for existing schema - it is one different task. But again: look at the inheritance.

Comment: I didn't mean one sequence for two tables - but yes I see that such a generated id is a very poor identifier because it will change as S-Man says below.  Thanks I'll will def. check inheritance as soon as I've checked if S-Man solutions makes my web framework happy, (& understood what the problem of the poor id's exactly means in my case).

Comment: S-Man solution is perfect for small tables. Use it if your data contains 10, 100 or even 1000 rows. However for billions rows you will need to find some another solution. Good luck!

Comment: I will look at inheritance!  I think you unintentionally explained to me what it is about -- one sequence for many tables... that's kind of exactly the problem here.. I wouldn't have known to think of that, but my guess is now you may be exactly right in pointing that out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199380/discussion-between-mwal-and-abelisto).

Comment: @Abelisto.  I consulted the postgres manual re. inheritance, however I was discouraged from using it because there are many warnings there which imply it is not solidly implemented yet. Have you personally used table inheritance in a significant production application over a significant period of time? I am not interested in bleeding edge things personally, they do not suit my situation.

Comment: Yes, in the one of projects with I working there is one base table `create table objects(id bigserial primary key not null, name text not null);` from which most other tables was inherited. It is useful for tasks like "find something in the whole DB by name" However I not force you to use inheritance. It is just a tool. Make your own decision is it useful for your task or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a row count to the `UNION` using the [`row_number(`) window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8ffbc6fe7c841b7f00cb5bbd9082c780)

```
CREATE VIEW v_myview AS

SELECT
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ...) AS id,
    *
FROM (
    SELECT ...
    UNION
    SELECT ...
) AS foo;
```

The main problem with this is: You should never deal with this id as an real identifier because the data of the table can change. So it could be that one table today generates a few records more than yesterday. So, the generated row numbers wouldn't match to the same record as before.

*Edit:* Removed the md5 solution I added before because of some problems with uniqueness on same data.

Comment: Do you know that the `UNION` operator will always check for duplicate rows which takes some additional time? `UNION ALL` is much faster.

Comment: @Abelisto Yes I know. In my fiddle I used the UNION ALL operator. I wanted the code to be as minimized as possible. For the question it doesn't matter. The opener already has a working UNION and is searching for an additional column.

Comment: Ok. Do you understand that your query will full scan for all tables to find one particular row?

Comment: @Abelisto And what do you want to tell me? The TO has nothing said about the data. Maybe it works for him, maybe the data set is too big, maybe the TO has set clever indexes or whatever. We don't know. As long as we don't know this, we have to wait for the TO's response. These are just two possible ways. If you know a better one, do not hesitate to post it.

Comment: I already post my *suggestion* in comments to question. What I want to say: your answer proposes probably most inefficient solution. I just want to point you to this to stop your wrong decision in the future :)

Comment: Thanks to both. I have no performance constraints currently, this is a prototype system where I have the luxury to pursue a pure design, e.g. no denormalisation at all which is wonderful for clarity of application code :)   I'll go in and do performance stuff later, IF and when the application needs it, not before.

Comment: @mwal What will be your goal when your DB grows to several terabytes?